# C++ back method for sub-range not found after chunking list

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

I came across this weird behaviour where if you create a chunked view, by 2 elements, of a list and then try to print the front and the back while in a ranged for loop, the front method will work, but the back method won't. It will produce a compiler error saying that instantiating the .back() method requires a bidirectional iterator.
Am I missing something?

**Code to reproduce the error**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::list<int> nums_list = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  auto rng = nums_list | std::views::chunk(2);
  for (auto pair : rng) {
    std::cout << pair.front(); // Front will work normally
    std::cout << pair.back();  // No matching member function for 'back'.
  }
}
```

I tried it with vector as well and it worked as expected.

Comment: from the error messages I see it look like the chunks are a model of a forward range which doesn't have a `back`

Comment: Looks like a bug. The requirement for `back()` to exist is that it's a [`common_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/common_range) and [`bidirectional_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/bidirectional_range) and I can't see why a `std::list` wouldn't fit - but a note in the `back()` doc says _"In C++20, no type derived from `std::ranges::view_interface` in the standard library provides their own `back()` member function."_

Comment: @TedLyngmo `std::list` is common and bidi, but a `chunk` out of it can't be - you'd have to walk the whole chunk to find the back.

Comment: @Barry Yes, I can understand the rationale behind that but in that case, is the wiki not updated or am I reading it wrong? It doesn't seem to require a random access iterator from what I can see. I'm suspecting I'm reading the `std::derived_from</*ITER_CONCEPT*/<I>` wrong. I really don't like these "exposition only" things. I find them hard to understand.

Comment: Facepalm! I was looking at the `chunk_view`, not its value type as 康桓瑋 points out in the answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It will produce a compiler error saying that instantiating the `.back()`
> method requires a bidirectional iterator. Am I missing something?

The `front()` member is provided only if the view inherited from `view_interface` satisfies `forward_range`, and the `back()` member is provided if both `common_range` and `bidirection_range` are satisfied.

`std::list` satisfies `common_range` and `bidirectional_range`, so `rng` is also `common_range` and `bidirectional_range`†, which allows you to use `back()` on it, for example:

```
std::list<int> nums_list = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto rng = nums_list | std::views::chunk(2);
auto back = rng.back();
```

However, the value type of `rng`, i.e. `pair` in your example, is specified as `decltype(views::take(subrange(current_, end_), n_))`†, where `current_`, `end_` are the iterators of the `std::list`.

Since `std::list::iterator` cannot be subtracted, that is to say, they do not satisfy `sized_sentinel_for`, this makes the `subrange` they construct not `sized_range`, which ultimately results in `take_view` not being `common_range`, so its `back()` synthesis fails.

---

† To support `back()`, `chunk_view` also needs to know the size of the underlying range to find the starting position of the last chunk. This is not a problem for `std::list` as it is a `sized_range`.

†
`views::take` is used here to automatically handle the situation where the number of the last chunk is less than `n`.